# What is the meaning of that message (with skimage on python)?

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I want to have informations about an image. Following [this docstring](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops) I wrote :

```
from skimage import morphology
from skimage import measure
skimage.morphology.label(labeled)
skimage.measure.regionprops(labeled)
```

I'm getting the message

> skimage.measure._regionprops._RegionProperties at 0x8754f98,
> skimage.measure._regionprops._RegionProperties at 0x8754828

What does it mean ?

Comment: It's just a printout of the `RegionProperties` objects returned by the `regionprops` function. You must use the `RegionProperties` object in order to get more information. http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops

Comment: You should capture the output of these functions, for example `props = skimage.measure.regionprops(labeled)`

Comment: Follow the docstring you linked to down to the example, and try and execute that first.  It shows how to capture the regions, and then extract attributes from them.  Also look at the examples gallery: regionprops are used in quite a few.